# How to combine two seqs (not using Seq.append)

Tags: f#

```
type Message =
    | Str of string
    | KeyPress of ConsoleKeyInfo

let keyStream = seq {
    while true do
        yield KeyPress(Console.ReadKey(true)) }

let rec messageStream = 
    keyStream |>
    Seq.combine (messageStream |> Seq.filter filterer) |> filterALot

messageStream |> Seq.iter (fun _ -> ())
```

Here is my code.  Basically I want to have a seq that handles console key presses, filters them to something, and sends some of them back in through the seq.  The problem is the Seq.combine method: it doesn't exist.  I could use append, but that adds them to the end of the keyStream seq, which is infinite.
I wish that when a keypress pushes a message out of the messageStream, that message could be inserted between the keypresses.

I hope my question is clear.  What should I clarify if it isn't?

And yes, this question does seem quite odd.

EDIT:
I just realized that messageStream really doesn't work.

What I am trying to do is take all the Console.ReadKey's and send them through a filter/mapper.  Anything that makes it through gets sent back in until nothing makes it through.

Comment: The question isn't too clear; what is the specific behaviour of the `Seq` function you're looking for? Eg. If you had two sequences `seq [ 1; 2; 3 ]` and `seq [ 4; 5; 6 ]` what would the function return?

Comment: @Quackmatic edited.  Hopefully that makes my real question clear.

Comment: So a function which repeatedly applies a function to each element in a sequence until they match some predicate?

Comment: @Quackmatic yeah, I guess.  I think I can figure it out, but if you give an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: all this looks really a lot like what you would do with Observables and Rx - have you had a look into those?

Comment: @Carsten yeah, but observable are really close to Seqs.  For this case, I don't think it would make any difference.

Comment: well the main difference here is that there already are all the combinators you need ;) (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229099(v=vs.103).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function like this, to repeatedly apply a function to a value until it satisfies a predicate (AFAIK this function doesn't exist in F# core):

```
let rec applyUntil pred f x = if pred x then x else applyUntil pred f (f x)
```

Then, just map using this function, like so:

```
let mapUntil pred f = Seq.map (applyUntil pred f)
```

In your case, you'd do something like:

```
mapUntil filterer transformer keyStream
```

This would repeatedly apply `transformer` to each element of the sequence until it matched `filterer`. From what I can tell from your question, this is what you're trying to do.